# How to set up ajax time out?

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout, settimeout

I have this code to time out ajax call after 40 secs:

```
if (xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", MY_SERVLET, true);              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = showResults;               
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    var httpTimeOut=setTimeout("ajaxTimeout();",40000);
            }

        function ajaxTimeout() {
            xmlhttp.abort();
        document.getElementById('errorShow').innerHTML = "Request Timed out";
            }
```

However I am unable to test this due to environment constraints at my place. Can anyone please tell if this is correct or any modifications are required??

Answer (score 11):

Should fix that:

```
if (xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", MY_SERVLET, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = showResults;               
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    setTimeout(function() {  xmlhttp.abort()  },40000);
```

since `ajaxTimeout` function can't "see" `xmlhttp` variable, but we can use anonymous function to have access to local variables.

Yet another approach is to use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so the library would take care of it.

Your code would look like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: MY_SERVLET,
    async: true,
    timeout: 40000,
    success: function(args) { 
        // on success code
    }
})
```